# Java Centring multiline JLabel Text properly

Tags: java, text, alignment

I need to centre two lines of text in a JLabel. My code is:

```
lblSolution.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
...
lblSolution.setText("<html>" + result.getNearest() + "<br>" + "<br>" + result.getSolutionString() + "</html>");
```

The problem is, it centres the longer of the two lines, and aligns the shorter at the same x position as the other.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
lblSolution.setText("<html><div style='text-align:center'>" + result.getNearest() + "<br>" + "<br>" + result.getSolutionString() + "</div></html>");
```